# Error: This class implements Parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field [ParcelCreator] in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

I am getting lint error `Error: This class implements Parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field [ParcelCreator]`

My data class:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class PhoneNumber(val countryCode:String, val number:String) : Parcelable{
    val completeNumber:String get() = countryCode + number
}
```

Kotlin version :

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
```

Plugins in `build.gradle` in `app` module

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'com.github.triplet.play' version '3.0.0'
  id 'kotlin-android'
  id 'kotlin-parcelize'
  id 'kotlin-kapt'
  id 'com.apollographql.apollo'
  id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

But in kotlin `1.3.61` i don't get lint error with `kotlin-android-extensions`

After migrating to `kotlin-parcelize` i am getting this lint error.

Please help me to resolve this lint error

Comment: I put your class into a scrap Android Studio Arctic Fox project, and I do not get this error. You might try creating your own scrap project and seeing if you get the error there.

Comment: @CommonsWare created a scrap project and didn't get this error. Any suggestion why getting this error? Is migration problem ?

Comment: "Any suggestion why getting this error?" -- my best guess is that you are somehow getting both plugins (`kotlin-android-extensions` and `kotlin-parcelize`) and that there is a conflict. That is just a guess, though.

Comment: Lint error resolved after upgrading `gradle` and  `triplet.play` version.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading

`com.android.tools.build:gradle` version `4.1.0` to `7.0.0`

and

`com.github.triplet.play` version `3.0.0` to `3.6.0`

lint issue resolved.